# How do I make a bone active using Python?

Tags: python, scripting

How to make a selected bone active in POSE or EDIT mode? Thanks!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/132630/how-to-make-a-bone-active   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/134250/set-active-bone-in-pose-mode-from-python-script

Answer (score 0):

Understood how in edit mode.

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
arm = bpy.data.armatures['Armature']
bone = arm.edit_bones["Bone"]
arm.edit_bones.active = bone
```

Comment: 'Object' object has no attribute 'edit_bones'

Answer (score 0):

```
bpy.context.object.data.bones.active = bpy.data.objects["rig"].pose.bones["spine_fk.003"].bone
```

This works in Blender 2.93 LTS, and a call to `bpy.context.object.data.bones.active` in pose mode will confirm that the bone you named is in there.
("rig" is the name of my armature, "Spine_fk.003" was the bone I happened to be using in a script).  However, it doesn't actually show the bone as being active on the screen.
If you select another bone on-screen, and then dump the code into the console, it will use whatever bone you dumped in there, but still show the other bone being active on-screen.
If you select a bone onscreen AFTER you put the code in, and then check the `bpy.context.object.data.bones.active`, it will list the one you clicked onscreen.

I honestly don't know if that's a bug, or what... I'm extremely new to this, but it seems to directly answer this question, at least for pose mode.